# ComboBox Binding on First Item in UWP C#

Tags: c#, combobox, binding, uwp

is there a way when I build an UWP app to select the first entry in a combobox in pure XAML? Normally I would set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`, but in UWP I only get an error that it cannot be set.
The `SelectedItem` does not work, only if I set it explicitly to the same as the `ItemsSource` with an [0] after it, but then the second `ComboBox` does not update on changes and shows empty entries again.
Here is my code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MainSystemComboBox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EditRulesViewModel.RuleSet.RuleMainSystems}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=EditRulesViewModel.RuleSet.RuleMainSystems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" />

<ComboBox x:Name="SubSystemComboBox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.RuleSubSystems, ElementName=MainSystemComboBox}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" />
```

Oh and it shows to me in the designer that the `Path` of the second `ComboBox` is incorrect, because it couldn't resolve property 'RuleSubSystems' in data context of type 'object', but after compiling it works well (except the selection of the first entry). Is there a cleaner way of binding one `ComboBox` to another?

Objects are simple

```
public class RuleMainSystem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Some more single properties...
    public ObservableCollection<RuleSubSystem> RuleSubSystems { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class RuleSubSystem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Some more single properties...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The SelectedItem does not work, only if I set it explicitly to the same as the ItemsSource with an [0] after it

You bind the `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` to the same one property `RuleMainSystems`, it's not correct. You would have to bind the SelectedItem to a specific item. E.g, `RuleMainSystems[0]`

> but then the second ComboBox does not update on changes and shows empty entries again.

That's because you have not bound `SelectedItem`, you need to do like the following:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SubSystemComboBox" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.RuleSubSystems, ElementName=MainSystemComboBox}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.RuleSubSystems[0], ElementName=MainSystemComboBox}"
      DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" />
```

***Updated on [2018/5/28]***

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="MainSystemComboBox" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RuleMainSystems}" 
      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
      DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="SubSystemComboBox" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding RuleSubSystems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SubSelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"
      DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" />
```

```cs
public class RuleMainSystem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Some more single properties...
    public ObservableCollection<RuleSubSystem> RuleSubSystems { get; set; }
}

public class RuleSubSystem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Some more single properties...
}
```

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new EditRulesViewModel();
}
```

```cs
public class EditRulesViewModel:ViewModelBase
{

    public ObservableCollection<RuleMainSystem> RuleMainSystems { get; set; }

    private RuleMainSystem _MySelectedItem;
    public RuleMainSystem MySelectedItem
    {
        get { return _MySelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _MySelectedItem = value;
            RuleSubSystems = MySelectedItem.RuleSubSystems;
            SubSelectedItem = MySelectedItem.RuleSubSystems.FirstOrDefault();
            RaisePropertyChanged("MySelectedItem");
        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<RuleSubSystem> _RuleSubSystems;
    public ObservableCollection<RuleSubSystem> RuleSubSystems
    {
        get { return _RuleSubSystems; }
        set
        {
            _RuleSubSystems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("RuleSubSystems");
        }
    }


    private RuleSubSystem _SubSelectedItem;
    public RuleSubSystem SubSelectedItem
    {
        get { return _SubSelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _SubSelectedItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SubSelectedItem");
        }
    }


    public EditRulesViewModel()
    {
        RuleMainSystems = new ObservableCollection<RuleMainSystem>();

        ObservableCollection<RuleSubSystem> SubSystems = new ObservableCollection<RuleSubSystem>();
        SubSystems.Add(new RuleSubSystem() {Name="Sub1" });
        SubSystems.Add(new RuleSubSystem() {Name="Sub2" });

        ObservableCollection<RuleSubSystem> SubSystems1 = new ObservableCollection<RuleSubSystem>();
        SubSystems1.Add(new RuleSubSystem() { Name = "Sub3" });
        SubSystems1.Add(new RuleSubSystem() { Name = "Sub4" });

        RuleMainSystems.Add(new RuleMainSystem() {Name="Rule1",RuleSubSystems = SubSystems });
        RuleMainSystems.Add(new RuleMainSystem() { Name = "Rule2", RuleSubSystems = SubSystems1 });
        MySelectedItem = RuleMainSystems.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: That works for the first call, like in the first ComboBox I mentioned. But as soon as I change the SelectedItem in the first ComboBox, I get an empty Second ComboBox (filled but nothing selected).

Comment: @MarcelGrüger Actually, the correct way to do this is to define a property to bind the `SelectedItem`. Please see my updated reply.

Comment: The update looks much better and is clearly undertandable, but there seems to be an important part missing (one error insinde). I cannot use a binding to the ItemsSource 'RuleSubSystems', because there is nothing with this name. If I bind to `Path=SelectedItem.RuleSubSystems, ElementName=MainSystemComboBox` I get the correct lists inside, but as soon as I change the MainComboBox the SubComboBox is unsetting the SelectedItem. It was called twice and the second time with a null value, so I added an if value == null return, but to no avail so far. I investigate further and tell what I can find.

Comment: Ok, after some testing I found out, that on the first call (where everything works as intended) the system calls the `GetXamlType` from the XamlTypeInfo.g.cs (an automatically created file). On the second call (where it doesn't work) it is not called. So maybe here is the problem. Maybe a bug in the UWP Databinding? Oh and I give you an upvote for your answer, because it is good and SHOULD work, but it is not the complete answer (yet).